# Critical points of a function of absolute value

Tags: calculus, terminology, definition

Say I have the function $f(x) = |x|$

I *believe* that $x = 0$ is a critical point, although not I'm not positive. As the function is decreasing and increasing each side of $x = 0$ does that alone make it a local minimum even though at $x = 0$ the function is not differentiable?

Comment: The concept of a [critical point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) $x_0$ is only defined if the function is differentiable at $x_0$. Since it isn't, you can neither assert nor deny that $x_0$ is a critical point. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was under the impression that a critical point was where $f'(x) = 0$ *or* if $f(x)$ was not differentiable but I might be wrong

Comment: Not according to wikipedia. I'm not sure how it usually is defined in calculus books, but I think it is the same as with wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of "local minimum" does not depend on the function being differentiable.

$0$ is a local minimum because $f(0)=0$ and there is a neighborhood of $0$ (namely the entire real line) such that $f(x)>f(0)$ for all $x\ne 0$ in that neighborhood.

**IF** the function is differentiable at the point in question, then you can use the derivative to gather information about whether it has a chance of being a local extremum or not. However, if it is *not* differentiable, then that tells you nothing at all about local maxima and minima. There may be one, or there may not; you need to go back to the actual definition for that.